# JTextArea not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class testFrame extends JFrame {

    public void draw(){
        setTitle("Asd");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(800, 600);

        Container cp = this.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane();

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        ta.setVisible(true);
        jp.add(ta);

        cp.add(jp);
    }

    public static void main(String argz[]){
        testFrame a = new testFrame();
        a.draw();
    }
}
```

However when I run it I can't see the JTextArea !

First I obtained the contentpane for my frame and set its layout as Borderlayout then I created a scrollpane and added a textarea to it. However when I run it I can't see the JTextarea !

Comment: Use `jp.setViewportView(ta)` or `new JScrollPane(ta)`

Comment: `setVisible(true);` should be last, and `setSize(800, 600);` should be `pack()` and immediately before the call to set the frame visible.

Answer (score 3):

```
jp.add(ta);
```

Don't add components to a JScrollPane.

Instead you add the component to the viewport of the scrollpane:

```
jp.setViewportView( ta );
```

Or the easier way is to just create the scroll pane using the text area as a parameter:

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(5, 20);
JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane( ta );  
cp.add( jp );
```

Comment: @Aditya See AndrewThompson's comment above